# Ground truth of a new datasets that have thousands of images

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, image-recognition, conv-neural-network

I am working on a dataset that contains thousands of images that does not have ground truth for segmentation. I checked online tools like "lable me", but it takes too much time for one picture and I have thousands of them. Are there any better methods?

Comment: you can start with an existing model (e.g., [masked rcnn](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06870)) and then manually refine these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of the top models such as ResNet/ Segnet to create ground truths,  which even serves your purpose.

I have found these github repos to be most reliable and easy to use,

1. SegNet : https://github.com/imlab-uiip/keras-segnet/blob/master/SegNet.ipynb
2. ResNet : https://github.com/raghakot/keras-resnet

Please be aware that all these models contains some errors. So its upto yo to decide whether those errors are significant enough to jeopardize your work